# Netbeans - error al Instalar en Linux

Tags: java, linux, debian

```
warren@warren-PC:~$ sudo snap install netbeans --classic
snap "netbeans" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

warren@warren-PC:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.9 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-post-Uos-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-post-Uos-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Alguien sabe porque cuando intento buscar la aplicación de Netbeans en mis aplicaciones instaladas bajo Deepin 20 (Debian) no me esta mostrando la aplicaciòn. Ya instale la manera para que las aplicaciones "Snap" puedan ser instaladas.

Les agradezco la ayuda :)

Comment: El mensaje dice que ya está instalada.

Answer (score 0):

Mira si puedes ejecutarla desde la terminal.

Si se ejecuta crea un .desktop (un .desktop es un acceso directo en linux).

Para crear uno sitúate en la carpeta  ~/.local/share/application

Y crea un archivo .desktop con nano

~/.local/share/application/netbeans.desktop

mi netbeans.desktop es así:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Apache NetBeans
Comment=Apache NetBeans, The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=netbeans %F
Categories=Development;IDE
Icon=netbeans
Terminal=false
```